# The expectation of a discrete random variable $X$ where $P(X=n)=\left(\frac12\right)^n$

Tags: probability

The problem is:

Find the expectation of a discrete random variable $X$ whose probability function is given by $$P(X=n)=\left(\frac12\right)^n$$

($n=1,2,3,4,5,\dots$)

Comment: Do you know the definition of expectation?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please, consider updating your question to include what you have tried and where you are getting stuck. That way, people on this site will know exactly what help you need.

Comment: Toss a fair coin until you get Heads.  What is the expected number of tosses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\mathbb E[X]=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\cdot\mathbb P[x=n]=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{2^n}$$

Now this here is just an arithmetico-geometric series, whose sum can be calculated with the following manipulations:

$$S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{2^n}$$
$$2S=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{2^n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{2^{n-1}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n+1}{2^n}=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n+1}{2^n}$$
$$2S-S=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n+1}{2^n}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{2^n}=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{2^n}$$

Now $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{2^n}$ is just a geometric series, whose sum is $1$, so $S=\mathbb E[X]=1+1=2$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

If $$f\left(x\right)=x+x^{2}+x^{3}+\cdots=\frac{x}{1-x}$$ then $$xf'\left(x\right)=x+2x^{2}+3x^{3}+\cdots$$

What do you recognize if you substitute $x=\frac12$?

Answer (score 0):

For $\;|x|<1\;$ we have

$$\frac1{1-x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k\implies\frac1{(1-x)^2}\stackrel *=\sum_{k=1}^\infty kx^{k-1}$$

Now, by definition:

$$E(X):=\sum_{n=0}^\infty n\cdot P(X=n)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty n\left(\frac12\right)^n=\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\left(\frac12\right)^{n-1}\stackrel *=\frac12\frac1{\left(1-\frac12\right)^2}=2$$